# Should I use fiber grip or grease when installing a bottom bracket into a carbon frame?

Tags: bottom-bracket, carbon

I am assembling my first carbon road bike and came across a question regarding on how to install the bottom bracket. I decided to go for this [Ninja BBRight](https://www.tokenproducts.com/bottom-brackets/item/549-TF37) for my Cervelo Caledonia.

The Token's instruction video shows the engineer applying grease on it, however it is an aluminium frame. Since I have a carbon frame, shall I use fiber grip instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grease. Allows the parts to come together smoothly, allows the threads to glide properly, seals out water, prevents corrosion, makes sure you can remove the parts again later.

Carbon assembly paste increases friction. It’s only really needed to prevent slipping for parts with low clamping force. The prime example are seatposts but it can also be useful for handlebars or stems.

If bearings or other parts are not seated perfectly (which leads to creaking) you can use retaining compound (e.g. Loctite 641).

Comment: [Official instructions](http://bbright.net/BBrightTM-Press-Fit-Instructions.pdf) from BBright (which I think only Cervelos use) do say clean off the grease first. They recommend Loctite when the fit is loose.